# Run SQL Queries on DataTables, or similar, in .Net, without an RDBMS

Tags: c#, .net, sql, vb.net, dataset

I'd like to have a dataset or datatables, and be able to run SQL statements on them, without using any external RDBMS.

For Example, to take take 2 datatables in a dataset and just join them outright with a SQL statement and Where clause, the result being a new datatable? For example if I have 2 datatables, named People and Addresses in a dataset (that I built using code, not getting from a database .. pardon the old fashioned Join syntax):

```
dim dtJoined as DataTable = MyDataSet.RunSQLQuery ("Select * from People, Orders Where People.PersonID=Orders.OrdereID")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not sql, but if you want to query datasets and datatables your best bet is to use [LINQ to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx)

Comment: It would be nice to be <strike>lazy</strike> efficient and not have to learn all the details of a new query language, but I guess LINQ is not that bad.

Comment: Once you start using it you might discover it is in many respects better than SQL. Eventually you might want to ditch the dataset approach altogether and use LINQ to query strongly typed collections or even databases via LINQ to SQL/Entity Framework/NHibernate etc.

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to be able to run SQL against it, because it isn't an RDBMS, but you can probably get what you want to accomplish using standard LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

You could write it out to a temp csv file and read it using OLEDB

```
string strCSVConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="
            + fileDirectory + ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;'";

OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, strCSVConnString);
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
oleda.Fill(dataTable);
```

In this case sql can be

```
SELECT * FROM fileName WHERE col = value
```

etc. We have had a fair amount of success with this.

Comment: That's awesome! I finally got a real answer. However, I have to admit, I've been storing everything in collections of lightweight classes or structs - usually with just public member vars - and using LINQ to even join multiple lists and have to recommend it. There are disadvantages - learning curve was the biggest, second biggest is you can't edit& continue (I have 2008) - but now I know it and am too addicted to go back. Note: there is a TON of stuff in .Net that is added to support this! Lambdas, Extension methods, etc.